# HTML Hash issue - IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, hashbang

Please have a time to read this post.

So, my web application is appending (/mypage to /mypage#hash) hash programmatically if it saw there's no hash yet, after logging in. In other browsers, even if the page has just appended a hash, when I click on browser's `Back` button it goes to login page (this behavior is what I wanted - /mypage#hash to /loginpage). But in IE8, after clicking `Back` button it goes to the same page but without hash (/mypage#hash to /mypage).

Any workaround or thoughts for this?? It's really appreciated. If its not clear enough, ask me. I'll make it clear to you.

Thanksss!!!!

Comment: What is the code you are using? Even if just providing a JSFiddle it will help?

Comment: I don't think JSFiddle will help this because I'm using SpringMVC in this. To make it simple, I want to have the hash already in the url, to make the `Back` button go to the page before it. Thx..

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
window.location.hash = 'hash';
```

Comment: I need to have a hash already in the url. setting a hash programmatically in `document ready` will make the `back redirect to no hash. I need it to not do that. any ideas? thx for the reply...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wether this might help but give it a try:

```
<head>
    <link rel="prev" title="" href="/loginpage">
<!-- ... -->
```

There is not much to influence the behaviour of a browser in this case.

You can of course always put up your own back link like

```
<a href="/loginpage">
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, but I cannot do this. I need to implement this on the browser's `Back` button.

Comment: Ohhh... Do you think there's a way to automatically have a hash in a url?